# Applescript: Get directory dropped on

Tags: applescript, directory

I have a applescript with the following:

```
on open dir
    tell application "Finder"
        tell application "Terminal"

            activate

            tell application "Terminal"

                do script "cd " & dir

            end tell
        end tell
    end tell    
end open
```

It works, and gets the directory thats dropped on it, but it cd's into cd Macintosh HD:Users:USER:Desktop:C Files:

Is there any way to replace : with / ? in applescript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the answer myself!:

set dir to quoted form of POSIX path of dir

Comment: Make sure to use the "quoted form" too. If the path has spaces you need it. As such just use...
do script with command "cd " & quoted form of POSIX path of dir